# Keyboard problems

Tags: keyboard

When I press for example button `m`, it appears on the screen `hm`. When I click `.` it appears `00.` and so on.

Is it problem with my keyboard or settings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your keyboard is malfunctioning. If pressing `.` results in `0..`, this has nothing to do with the regional or keyboard settings. You can just plug in a working keyboard to make sure your keyboard is broken.